# Isn't the structure of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3))$ just the structure of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2))$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Isn't the structure of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt3))$ just the structure of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2))$?
    I'm getting confused about common algebra notation. What does it mean when a field extension is "divided" by another, smaller field extension (see title)? I know divided isn't the right word for what is really happening here, but I'm not sure of the correct way to phrase it.
I know what I am supposed to do when finding the structure of $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3))$, but I am confused about notation. It's a small thing I should already know, but now that I don't it is causing me problems.

Comment: If by "structure" you mean isomorphism class (for groups) then you are right. Another thing when we write $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ this is not "a field extension divided by another", this is just a field extension, rigorously the data for an extension $L/K$ is two fields $L$ and $K$ with a morphism of ring $f:K\rightarrow L$. (necessarily an injection). As in most case, the morphism is forgotten here since there is an obvious inclusion of  $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Comment: The solidus (“$/$”) is just mathematical shorthand for “over”. When I saw that a student was thoroughly confused by the notation “$L/K$”, thinking it was like the quotient notation $G/H$ for $H$ a normal subgroup of $G$, I decided that when it was fields I was talking about,I would always write $L\supset K$ instead of $L/K$. (I notice that some people are now writing $L|K$ instead. That’s good too.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $K\subset L$ is a subfield (equivalently, $L/K$ is a field extension), then the group
$$\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)=\{\phi\in\mathrm{Aut}(L)\mid \phi|_{K}=1_K\}.$$
In words, these are the automorphisms of $L$ that fix $K$ pointwise.

In the case $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, you are correct that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)\cong\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}_2$.

Note that in this context, $\mathrm{Gal}(L/K)$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ (the automorphisms of $L$ that fix $K$ pointwise forms a subset of the set of all automorphisms of $L$), whereas $\mathrm{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})/\mathbb{Q})$ is not a subgroup (the domains of the relevant automorphisms are different).

Answer (score 2):

There’s a theorem sometimes called the Theorem on Natural Irrationalities—it says that if $K$ and $L$ are extensions of a field $k$, and if $L$ is Galois over $k$, then the Galois group of $KL$ over $K$ is isomorphic to the group of $L$ over $K\cap L$, and in a very natural way. Looks like a tall order to satisfy, but the case $k=\Bbb Q$, $K=\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$, $L=\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$ fits, since the intersection is $\Bbb Q$. So in that sense, the extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)\supset\Bbb Q(\sqrt3)$ is, in that sense “just like” the extension $\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)\supset\Bbb Q$.